# Allow external useer to start/stop compute engine instance - different behavior

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, virtual-machine, roles, google-iam

As from the title need to allow an external user to start/stop the instance he will work on and nothing else, it's a topic I found already answers, and did setup for the specific project the a custom role "StartStopCE" with these permissions:

```
compute.instances.get
compute.instances.list
compute.instances.osLogin
compute.instances.reset
compute.instances.resume
compute.instances.start
compute.instances.stop
compute.instances.suspend
serviceusage.services.list
```

Testing with one of my secondary Google accounts (not the one I'm Owner in GCP) all is working fine and I'm allowed only to list the VM Instances and start/stop/etc.

The external user was allowed to do so only the first time we was experiementing with the various persmissions, next when he tried to start the instance this disappeared after he started it, and after that he got only this page trying to access the VM Instances list
[image: Error trying to list GCP VM instances from external user]

We have tried to delete and recreate his user, use a second Google user, logout/login, change browser, delete cache.

My test user has the very same assigned role and worked fine, I don't know what elese to check.

Comment: What's an external user for you? How do you grant it?

Comment: Can you share the role on IAM of the user? Also try to add Compute Admin Role on the user.. IAM > Edit User > Add Another Role > Compute Engine > Compute Admin.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere an external user is someone outside our company, a professional we are collaborating with. So far I just set an IAM profile with his Google mail account.

Comment: @JaysonM I have create a StartStopCE role with these permissions   <br/> - compute.instances.get
- compute.instances.list
 - compute.instances.osLogin
 - compute.instances.reset
 - compute.instances.resume
 - compute.instances.start
 - compute.instances.stop
 - compute.instances.suspend
 - serviceusage.services.list

Comment: Just looking now at the IAM entries I noticed my Google user I tested with this role show an 0/9 excess permissions, the first external user account I have had setup for the professional show a 3/9 excess permissions, the second user account I have had setup for him (the idea was maybe the problem was related to one of his Gmail accounts) show 9/9 excess permissions. Did't know if this mean anything.